Visualizing histogram of data on unit circle?
I'm looking for a nice way to visualize histogram of data on unit circle. Perhaps by using 3D-cylinder with height proportional to the density, what's the best way to reuse built-in functionality to achieve this effect?
Below is an example of circular data generated from random matrices:

negateFirstRow[A_] := {-A[[1, All]]}~Join~A[[2 ;;, All]];
sampleO[n_] := RandomVariate@CircularRealMatrixDistribution@n;
sampleSO[n_] := 
  With[{mat = sampleO@n}, If[Det[mat] > 0, mat, negateFirstRow@mat]];

n = 4;
numSamples = 20000;
data = Flatten@
  Table[Eigenvalues@sampleSO@n, {numSamples}];
ComplexListPlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Opacity[.001]}]

Background: Histogram of angular data without edge aliasing?

RadialAxisPlot? Circular histogram?

Or maybe a SectorChart3D like this? I am not 100% sure how to use SectorChart3D yet so i'm just leaving this as a comment suggestion

@Domen I agree 2D is the way to go -- no accidental biases or misinterpretations from 3D vantage points, etc.

Or...
  data = Table[{1, 1, RandomReal[{0, 10}]}, {100}]; 
  SectorChart3D[{{0, 0, 0}, data},
  ChartStyle -> Green,
  SectorSpacing -> 4]


Note that you can click and drag the computed chart to view it from different angles and orientations.


If you're data is smooth enough, plotting a color function on a circle could be an option.
Maybe something like this. Here I'm using data defined in the question:
n = 100;
cpts = Exp[I*Most[Subdivide[0., 2 \[Pi], n]]];

cnts = Lookup[Counts[Nearest[cpts -> "Index", data][[All, 1]]], Range[n], 0];

closeData[data_] := Append[data, First[data]]

Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[30], CapForm[None], 
  Line[ReIm[closeData[cpts]], VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ 
   Rescale[closeData[cnts]])]}, 
  Axes -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, GrayLevel[0.8]}
]



Or we can make a sector-type histogram:
annularSector[z_, n_, r_] := Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 1 + r}, Arg[z] + π/n {-1, 1}]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Lighter[ColorData[112, 3]], 
  MapThread[
   Tooltip[annularSector[#1, n, #2], Arg[#1] -> #3] &, 
   {cpts, 0.01 + 0.3 Rescale[N@cnts], cnts}]}, 
  Axes -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, GrayLevel[0.2]}
]


We can achieve a similar graphic with SectorChart too:
SectorChart[{1, 0.01 + 0.3 #} & /@ Rescale[cnts], 
  SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
  ChartStyle -> Lighter[ColorData[112, 3]], 
  Axes -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, GrayLevel[0.2]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None
]


If you are sticking with histograms, then your original histogram is simple to program, easy to interpret, and easy to glean specific density values.
negateFirstRow[A_] := {-A[[1, All]]}~Join~A[[2 ;;, All]];
sampleO[n_] := RandomVariate@CircularRealMatrixDistribution@n;
sampleSO[n_] := 
  With[{mat = sampleO@n}, If[Det[mat] > 0, mat, negateFirstRow@mat]];

n = 4;
numSamples = 1000000;
data = Flatten@Table[Eigenvalues@sampleSO@n, {numSamples}];

Histogram[Arg[data], {-\[Pi], \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100}, "PDF",
 PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi] - 0.1, \[Pi]}, {0, Automatic}}, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Table[-\[Pi] + 2 \[Pi]  i/10, {i, 0, 10}], None}}]


But I understand the desire for something that displays the fact that one has a "circular" random variable.  So far the other answers have a lot of white space and I would argue that specific density values are not so easily discerned.
One possibility is to consider is the following:

Here I've connected the estimated densities for each of the histogram bins (as I increased the sample size and the number of bins as it appears you have complete control over that).  Note that the circles of equal density are on a square root scale (see @whuber 's answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608370/radial-axis-transformation-in-polar-kernel-density-estimate for an explanation).
The advantage of this approach is that if the objective is to compare multiple distributions, you can overlay the densities.  But if one only saw this figure, most folks wouldn't be able to see that there are distinct peaks and valleys.  So I'd still argue that a nonparametric density estimate on a linear figure with values going from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ makes for a more interpretable display.  Less sexy but easier to interpret.
Below is the code I used and it shows that I don't know how to work very well with ListPolarPlot and SectorPlot (especially with constructing different scaling factors).
h = HistogramList[Arg[data], {-\[Pi], \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100}, "PDF"];
\[Theta]r = Transpose[{(h[[1, 2 ;;]] + h[[1, 1 ;; Length[h[[2]]]]])/2, Sqrt[h[[2]]]}];
\[Theta]r = Join[\[Theta]r, {\[Theta]r[[1]]}];
Show[
 ListPolarPlot[\[Theta]r, Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> {True, False}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0.2, ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotRange -> {{-Sqrt[0.5], Sqrt[0.5]}, {-Sqrt[0.5], Sqrt[0.5]}},
  Ticks -> {None, {{Sqrt[0.01], 0.01}, {Sqrt[0.05], 0.05}, {Sqrt[0.1], "0.10"},
     {Sqrt[0.15], 0.15}, {Sqrt[0.20], "0.20"}, {Sqrt[0.25], 0.25}}},
  PolarTicks -> {Table[-\[Pi] + 2 \[Pi]  i/20, {i, 20, 0, -1}], Automatic}],
 Graphics[{LightGray,
   Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.25]],
   Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.20]],
   Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.15]],
   Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.10]],
   Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.05]],
   Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.01]],
   Style[Text["-  0.00", {0, 0}, {-1, 0}], Black, Bold],
   Style[Text["-  0.01", {0, Sqrt[0.01]}, {-1, 0}], Black, Bold],
   Style[Text["-  0.05", {0, Sqrt[0.05]}, {-1, 0}], Black, Bold],
   Style[Text["-  0.10", {0, Sqrt[0.10]}, {-1, 0}], Black, Bold],
   Style[Text["-  0.15", {0, Sqrt[0.15]}, {-1, 0}], Black, Bold],
   Style[Text["-  0.20", {0, Sqrt[0.20]}, {-1, 0}], Black, Bold],
   Style[Text["-  0.25", {0, Sqrt[0.25]}, {-1, 0}], Black, Bold]}],
 ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.5}}, PlotStyle -> Black, Joined -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Ticks -> {None, {0.2, 0.3, 0.4}}]]


We can convert the data to 2D real data, and use Histogram3D:
real2D = ReIm @ data;
Histogram3D[real2D]


Or SmoothHistogram3D with a lower density floor added to the PlotRange (I'm not sure how good the automatic bandwidth selection is for this case):
SmoothHistogram3D[real2D, PlotRange -> {All, All, {10^-2, 1}}]



I don't think this is a good way to represent data lying on the circle, because the bins lie on the square grid. Try with uniformly distributed points, and you will observe the artefacts.

@Domen Ah I see, good point.
